# jcombo getSelected in drag and drop

Tags: java, events, jcombobox

hi i wanted to ask how to use combo boxes because i need to change a check box caption.
i got nokia,samsung on the drop down. and then 3 check boxes. so if i clicked on nokia, i want to see 3 nokia chkboxes. and so on if samsung. i know that this is simple, but its hard to know the methods. i'm a visual basic user, so its kinda hard. pls make it simple, i am using DnD. also i used action perform.

here's my code for now. but its not working, it only shows samsung chk boxes

```
private void      

phoneComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)          {                                           
String Nokia;
String Samsung;


Nokia = (String)phoneCombo.getSelectedItem();
checkBox1.setText("Nokia E71");
checkBox2.setText("Nokia E72");
checkBox3.setText("Nokia E79");

Samsung=(String)phoneCombo.getSelectedItem();
checkBox1.setText("Samsung D780");
checkBox2.setText("Samsung D880");
checkBox3.setText("Samsung F480");

}                  `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a condition
`if phoneCombo.getSelectedItem("Nokia) then // put your code here`